# How to open the Database .mdf file without any Server connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

im a newbie at C# and Database's. I need your help. I use Visual Studio C# Gui and SQL Server Managment Studio from Microsoft.

My problem:
I have a Database at SQL Server Managment. Im only able to view it when im connectet about Datagridview in Visual Studio C#. (y thats pretty normal). Now, i want to copy the Database file (.mdf and .ldf) and use it, when im not connectet to view it. Only to view.

```
 SqlCeConnection myConnection2 = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\XX\Desktop\XX\Database.mdf");
                    SqlCeDataAdapter sda = new SqlCeDataAdapter("Select* FROM Database", myConnection2);
                   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    myConnection2.Open();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    dgv_Test.DataSource = dt;
```

This is not working!

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't know how to use your SQL without a connection but you could just make a mock repository and put fake data into that. Then you can just call that repo to have a fake database.

Comment: how does work? Could u give me more informations (Link, video etc) about mock and fake data? im a newbie :)

Comment: Your question is unclear in what you really want. Plus your connection string is wrong, in the first line, to fix it look for example connection strings to SQL. Next on line two, in SQL you will select * from a table, not a database. Fix your connection string, and then change to list a table and you should be ok.